# Flipping a grouped wordcloud in quanteda

Tags: text-mining, word-cloud, quanteda

I am fairly new to this and have a small general question - when we do a 2-group comparison word-cloud using quanteda.textplot, what determines which group comes out on top? My groups were named c("Pos","Neg") and neg was coming on top. I changed "Neg" to "cNeg" and "CNeg" to no effect. It appears that the order is determined by the total frequency of words in the two groups. Is there a way to flip the word-cloud?

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple: the categories are taken from the order of the documents (rows) in the document-feature matrix.  So if your grouped dfm has documents "Pos", "Neg", then just reorder the rows before calling `quanteda.textplots::textplot_wordcloud()`.

Example:

```r
library("quanteda")
#> Package version: 3.2.1
#> Unicode version: 14.0
#> ICU version: 70.1
#> Parallel computing: 10 of 10 threads used.
#> See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.
library("quanteda.textplots")

dfmat2 <- data_corpus_inaugural %>%
    corpus_subset(President %in% c("Obama", "Trump")) %>%
    tokens(remove_punct = TRUE) %>%
    tokens_remove(stopwords("en")) %>%
    dfm()
dfmat2 <- dfm_group(dfmat2, dfmat2$President) %>%
    dfm_trim(min_termfreq = 3)

# Obama first
textplot_wordcloud(dfmat2, comparison = TRUE, max_words = 50,
                   color = c("blue", "red"))
```

[image]

```r
# flip it
textplot_wordcloud(dfmat2[c(2, 1), ], comparison = TRUE, max_words = 75,
                   color = c("red", "blue"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>